# Zend - Regex allow whitespace and unicode characters

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, validation

I have a problem with an regular expression which allow me to put a name lets say if an institution which can contain special characters for other languages, white space and - char.
I know that expression i created:

```
/^[a-zA-Z- "\']*$/
```

will allow chars from a to z and -'" chars and white space. But when i type żźćąś or other languages special chars string is not valid, but i want it to be valid.

Second expression which i created:

```
/^[^\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\`\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\_\\+\\=\\{\\}\\:\\"\\;\\\\\<\\>\\?\\,\\.\\/\ ]*$/
```

allows a-z characters without characters disallowed above. But I dont disallow white space in regex above but when i type something with space like that for example:

`"Bielsko Biała"`

Its not valid, but when i type it together:

`"BielskoBiała"`

it is valid with ą character. So i'd like to allow special chars like żźćąśł and others from other languages but also like to allow white spaces and i dont knot how to do it.

When i was using Alpha validator it was ok but dont allow to put -'" chars which i also want to allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to enable UTF-8 support with the `u` switch. Then you can match unicode letters with the sequence `\pL`. See [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

So your solution would be

```
/^[\pL- "\']*$/u
```

Comment: correst me if i'm wrong. pl means polish special chars yes? so i have to add other languages shortcuts also to allow other languages special chars?

Comment: `L` means all letters :) ok it works as it should ;) now i understand ;) thank You. Problem solved

Comment: you can select languages by `\p{Language}`. The list of languages is provided in the link above.